# Select all the cells from the active cell down until a blank cell and paste values

Tags: vba, excel

I need to select all the cells from the active cell down until a blank cell and then paste them as values only.

I am using this line but this is copying all the formatting.

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy Range("C10")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it as direct value transfer.

```
with Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
    .parent.Range("C10").resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .value
end with
```

For raw values without regional currency or date 'markers', change .Value to .Value2. (e.g. 26/06/2017 becomes 42912)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy and paste the values only and not the formatting as well then you can use the the paste special method.

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
Range("C10").PasteSpecial operation:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = True
```

Use the xlPasteValues operation to only paste the values and not the formatting.
Application.CutCopyMode will get rid of the 'dancing ants' around the selection.